# React Native API data

Tags: react-native

I have a class that is getting data from API and it returns an array.

In a file that I am calling it like this:

```
let defaultMenu2 = '';
import GetCategories from '../constants/tabs';

GetCategories.renderTabs().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    defaultMenu2 = response;
});
console.log('response----------' + defaultMenu2);
```

console.log is displaying array perfectly (in console), but variable "defaultMenu2" is always empty.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Can anybody explain how to persist variables, definitely not getting why I cannot overwrite variable or object...

tried this:

```
let tabs2 = new Object();
GetCategories.renderTabs().then((response) => {
    //console.log(response);
    tabs2 = response;
    alert('number 1 response #########'+JSON.stringify(tabs2));
});

alert('response#########' + JSON.stringify(tabs2));
```

"number 1 response #########" alert is displaying perfectly what I need, but other "response#####" alert is empty object.

1. There is a file tabs.js with data:

   export default tabs = {
       deals: [
           { id: 'communityPartner', title: 'Community Partner13' },
           { id: 'localBusiness', title: 'Local Business' },
           { id: 'nonProfit', title: 'Non Profit' },
           { id: 'help', title: 'Help' },
           { id: 'volunteer', title: 'Volunteer' },
           { id: 'student', title: 'Student' },
           { id: 'thankYou', title: 'Thank You' },
       ],
   };
2. There is new file tabs2.js with API call to real data:

   const APItabs = 'https://.........tabs.json';

   export default class GetCategories {
       static renderTabs = async () => {
           tabsArrayholder = [];
           return await fetch(APItabs)
               .then((response) => response.json())
               .then((responseJson) => {
                   tabsArrayholder = responseJson;
                   return tabsArrayholder;
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                   console.error(error);
               });
       };
   }
3. In the file Screens.js there is a call to tabs.js (dummy data):

   import tabs from '../constants/tabs';

than data is rendered as tabs.deals.... without any problems.

4. I added tabs2.js to Screens.js (once it start working it should replace tabs...

   let tabs2 = new Object();
   import GetCategories from '../constants/tabs2';

   GetCategories.renderTabs().then((response) => {
       tabs2 = response;
       alert('number 1 response #########' + JSON.stringify(tabs2));
   });

   alert('response#########' + JSON.stringify(tabs2));

My intention was to rename tabs2 into tabs.. so all the code afterwards would be the same.

Problem is I think that code below GetCategories.renderTabs().... is rendered before there is replay from GetCategories.renderTabs()....

Comment: From your example it appears like renderTabs returns something PromiseLike, which suggests it happens asynchronously. That means that most probably the effect from `then` executes after you print 'response----------'. Have a look at the [canonic React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) example for how to retrieve data asynchronously, using the `useEffect` and `useState` hooks.

Comment: Your console is calling before your data is getting stored in defaultMenu2, that's the reason you are getting it as empty.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question with all code... so it might be clearer. I have external file that makes API call, then in the main file it was dummy call for data, that I wanted to replace with real data. I wanted to store it on the same variable name so that I don't change a lot of code. Have a look at the main question I am updating code now...

Comment: as @artcorpse mentioned, you have to use the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks in order to be able to retrieve async data